# Can I get Razor to use some form input as part of the form action URI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a problem with setting correct action attribute value using ASP.NET MVC routing mechanism.

I am using `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in `RouteConfig` class and I am setting URL address for every action by myself. And now I want form to move to defined URL address after I submit it, but there in no correct URL in action attribute (or there is none).

Here is code I use.

Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("search")]
public class SearchController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search/{query}/{author?}/{category?}/{mediaType?}/{color?}/{resultPerPage?}/{startElement?}", Name = "Search_Search")]
    public ActionResult Search(string query, string author = "none", int category = 0, int mediaType = 0, int color = 0, int resultsPerPage = 15, int startElement = 0)
    {
            //doing some stuff here...
    }
}
```

And now the .cshtml file fragment:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
{
}
```

Action attribute in generated form is like "/Search/Search", but that address does not work (404 error). I've tried use `Html.BeginRouteForm` with and without additional route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SearchFormRoute",
    url: "search/search/{query}/{author}/{category}/{mediaType}/{color}/{resultPerPage}/{startElement}",
    defaults: new
    {
        author = "none",
        category = 0,
        mediaType = 0,
        color = 0,
        resultsPerPage = 15,
        startElement = 0
    },
    constraints: new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET")
    }
);
```

I have tried it two ways, `Html.BeginRouteForm("SearchFormRoute")` and `Html.BeginRouteForm("Search_Search")`. Sometimes action attribute is set (but it's incorrect) and sometimes it's empty.

I really don't know how I shoud set it all up to work correctly. Is there any way to redirect form to manually defined with routing settings URL address?

**EDIT: added whole form code**

There is form code I am using:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="col-md-9 nopadding">
                    <input type="text" id="query" name="query" class="form-control navSearchInput" placeholder="search...">
                </div>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="navSearchButton" type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**EDIT: added generated form code**

```
<form action="/Search/Search" method="get">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="col-md-9 nopadding">
                    <input type="text" id="query" name="query" class="form-control navSearchInput" placeholder="search...">
                </div>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="navSearchButton" type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That route is horrible.

Comment: Yeah, it is, but I need to have URL like that I am just trying to make it work.

Comment: How are you encountering the 404 error?  Is it by manually accessing `/Search/Search`?  Or is the 404 on the form post?

Comment: ps: maybe posting your form code would be useful

Comment: @SimonKittle I posted it

Comment: @SimonKittle I get 404 error whatever I send form or go to that address manually.

Comment: Which address manually?  And what is the HTML being output by the `BeginForm`?

Comment: I posted generated HTML code, and I mean `/Search/Search` URL address (or `/Search/Search/?query=abc`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95561/discussion-between-mateusz-cisek-and-simon-kittle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to access `/Search/Search` (just that) you'll get a `404` because your `query` route parameter is required.  Any requests to `/Search/Search` will therefore not match a route.

But the same is true of requests of the form `/Search/Search?query=blah`, because your route is requiring that `query` be a route parameter, whereas here `query` is coming from the query string.  So again, `404`.

To get what you want you'll have to use Javascript to handle the form submission, and make sure that `query` is part of the route.  Something like:

```
$("formIdHere").on("submit", function () { 
    this.action += WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD; 
    this.submit(); 
});
```

Comment: When I manually try to access `/Search/Search?query=abc` I am getting 404 error, but the reason is I've set manually route for that action and it's no longer available at this address. Still, it's not an issue here. I can manually access `/search/search/abc/none/0/0/0/15/0` and it's working just fine, but I want the form to redirect to this address and insert given in input query to the correct place in URL.

Comment: Okay, and what is the value of the form action that you say is broken?  Post some of the HTML its producing.  Is the form going anywhere?

Comment: With form code posted below I get `<form action="/Search/Search" method="get">`. And when I send it I am being redirected to `/Search/Search?query=abc`, but what I want is to be redirected to `/search/search/abc/none/0/0/0/15/0`.

Comment: Right, I see.  To do that you'd have to use Javascript I believe; standard form submissions using `GET` will append things to the query string in the way you've described - that's just how it works.  To get what you want, you'd have to have some Javascript handle the submission.  You get the `404` error with the query string version because it doesn't match a route - you're route requires `query` to be a route parameter.

Comment: So there is no reason to redirect it automatically to defined URL? And my `query` parameter is defined in route config, `[Route("search/{query}/{author?}/{category?}/{mediaType?}/{color?}/{resultPerPage?}/{startElement?}", Name = "Search_Search")]`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: It's pretty simple, I want to be redirected automatically to defined in `Route` URL addres after submitting form and I want the query to be automatically inserted in correct place in that URL. So I want razor to generate correct action attribute value based just on value of `Route` attribute in controller file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95560/discussion-between-simon-kittle-and-mateusz-cisek).

Comment: I am using javascript now and it's working, so I think my problem is resolved.